# htaccess wont rewrite right

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need this script to rewrite a url from for example "website.com/index.php?id=1/" to "website.com/1", but I can't get it to work. Why wont this code work and what can I do to make it work?

input: http://example.com/index.php?id=1
output: http://example.com/-?id=1

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L]
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L]

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Then it displays the root of the website :/ the htaccess file is supposed to be located with the rest of the website files, right?

Comment: This was assuming .htaccess is in document root of website. In what folder you have kept it? And for URL are you getting problem?